# Is there any difference between "the flight / train / bus / coach... for New York" & ".... to New York"?

Tags: prepositions

Is there any difference between "**the flight / train / bus / coach... for New York**" & "**the flight / train / bus / coach... to New York**"?

[In the Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/for_1?q=for)

> For (preposition): used to show where somebody/something is going;
>   used to say where a person, vehicle etc is going
>
> *Is this the bus for Chicago?*

But we can also say

> *She booked a flight to Chicago.* [Source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/book_2)

Answer (score 2):

Both are acceptable, and there is no difference between them.

Note however that they are interchangeable only in this context, as complement of a noun designating a mode or means of transportation; they introduce an ***intended*** destination. As complement of a verb of motion, *to* usually introduces an ***achieved*** destination: *She drove **to** Chicago* implies that she reached Chicago. *For* is rare with such verbs, but if you encounter it it will introduce an intended destination, with no implication that the destination was achieved.

Comment: Why did you use **archieved** instead of **reached** in your last sentence?

Comment: @SovereignSun 'cause that's the term I introduced (and boldfaced) as a contrast to *intended*.

Comment: I always thought that "...for Chicago" meant that the *purpose* of the train was to take you to Chicago.

Comment: @user3169 I have no idea where the idiom originated: it could equally be a train *for* passengers to Chicago or a train *bound* or *headed for* Chicago. But the object of the preposition is the intended destination.